# How to install Visual SourceSafe 2005?

Tags: version-control

OK, this would seem old and odd...but it still needs to be done.

We actually have a file server (NAS) that has VSS 6.0 on it, basically the .exe files, etc. are in a share and the users run the .exe file to open VSS and check in/out documents.

I've downloaded VSS 2005 from our MVLS site and extracted it and read the readme.htm saying that I can install in on a server running setup.exe.

The question I have:

Q:  How can I setup VSS 2005 as just files on a share where the user can then run the .exe file like our existing VSS 6.0 setup?  Is it really as easy as simply copying the extracted files over to the share?  I don't want to actually have to install a server side application for it if not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can have the repository (vss database) files shared via a network share thats how the multi-user aspects are claimed.

I believe VSS 6 had a network install option and just installing VSS 2k5 now to confirm this option still exists. This means you only need to get all your clients to run the .exe from this share and login to the repository on another share.

Oh, PLEASE create a repository for EVERY project! VSS can become easily corrupted.....

Will update this post if there is a network install option for VSS 2k5

EDIT: Ok, no network setup under the installer but you could try copying the Microsoft Visual SourceSafe folder under the Program Files folder on the install medium to a network share. Please test this and ensure it does not corrupt a repository before using this method for production work

Comment: Thanks Wayne,

I'll start my own test install now and see what it looks like.  Just didn't want to mess with it until I understood how it could be working now in VSS 6.

Comment: Tested and so far it works fine.  The team that wants this says they are willing to live with the risks, so good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

The server portion of VSS needs to go onto an actual server running Windows.

Unfortunately it's not as easy as a simple file share. The server is responsible for adjudicating transactions, check-ins, check-outs, timestamping, etc.

Comment: Are you able to explain how it is working currently then?  I'm not sure how it is even working but it is.  Nothing is installed on the server (it's a Netapp Filer), and the clients simply run the client .exe file on the file share.

Comment: Actually VSS is a simple file share.  There is no real server component.  There is an admin tool and a corruption checking tool (which should be run every night cause VSS is a POS).